# Garbage is printed out when a number bigger than 127 is entered

Tags: c

I try to write a program that prints out a decimal number as a binary number. If I enter a number bigger than 127, garbage is printed out. How to fix this bug?

The problem appears in the following line:

```
printf("%s\n", bits);
```

Probably the function print_decimal_number_binary(int) is incorrect.
I know that I actually have to reverse the binary string before I print it out, I will implement this after the bug is fixed.

Thank you very much for helpful comments!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 1

void print_decimal_number_binary(int number)
{
    char bits[sizeof(int) * 8 + 1];
    int index = 0;

    if (number == 0)
    {
        printf("0\n");
        return;
    }

    while (number > 0)
    {
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            bits[index] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            bits[index] = '1';
        }
        number = number / 2;
        index++;
    }

    printf("%s\n", bits);
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf("This program only works for positive integers.\n\n");
    while (TRUE)
    {
        // display main menue and get choice
        printf("[1] decimal to binary\n");
        printf("[2] binary to decimal\n");
        printf("[0] leave program\n");
        printf("Input: ");
        char main_menue_choice;
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf(" %c", &main_menue_choice);
        printf("\n");

        // handle user input
        if (main_menue_choice == '1')
        {
            printf("number: ");
            int number;
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf(" %i", &number);
            printf("\n");
            print_decimal_number_binary(number);
        }
        else if (main_menue_choice == '2')
        {
            printf("number: ");
            char number_string[sizeof(int) * 8 + 1];
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf(" %s", &number_string);
            printf("\n");
            print_binary_number_decimal(number_string);
        }
        else if (main_menue_choice == '3')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Enter a valid argument!");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of `#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 1`. Use `stdbool.h` instead. Get rid of `fflush(stdin)`, it is undefined behavior. Terminate your `bits` string with `\0` - that's your problem.

Comment: BTW, `#define FALSE 1` - seriously?

Comment: ooops, that is a mistake...

Comment: This is why using homebrew boolean types and constants is evil.

Comment: Append a `\0` at the end of `bits`.

Comment: Or better still, initialise `bits` as an array of zeros.

Comment: Note: `if (number == 0)
    {
        printf("0\n");
        return;
    }` not needed if code uses a `do { ... } while (number > 0);` loop instead of the following `while { ...}`.

Comment: "Append a \0 at the end of bits" has the advantage over "initialise bits as an array of zeros." as it is more performance efficient.  O(1) vs. O(n).  A minor concern with  small arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour because you do:

- `fflush(stdin)`
- haven't zero terminated `bits` array which you later print as a string.

Do:

```
char bits[sizeof(int) * 8 + 1] = {0};
```

which initializes the whole array `bits` with zeros (thus it'll naturally have the zero terminator for `bits`) and get rid of all `fflush(stdin)` calls; `fflush` is only defined for output streams in standard C.

You also don't need the leading white-space in format string for scanning ints (`%i`) and strings (`%s`) as they already ignore previous white-spaces.

And drop the `&` here:

```
scanf(" %s", &number_string);
```

`number_string` when passed to `scanf` already decays to `char*` which is what `scanf` expects for a `%s`. What you currently pass to `scanf` is of type `char (*)[33]` which is wrong for `%s`.

Comment: I had the problem that he sometimes skipped my scanf statements. The leading whitespace solved that problem.

Comment: Usually you'd face that when scanning `char`'s (`%c` doesn't skip whitespaces). As a general suggestion, avoid scanf. See: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html